cannot connect to C++ kernel in jupyter using xeus-cling
I just run these code to install the xeus-cling on my mac
conda create -n cling
conda activate cling
conda install jupyter notebook
conda install xeus-cling -c conda-forge
jupyter kernelspec list


and it shows that I have C++ 11 14 17 kernels but when I open my jupyter notebook, I cannot connect to the kernel with an error says that is_trivially_destructible is not implemented
Can anyone help me?
I have tried to download the xcode but it doesn't work.
